# Get correct current user in mysql under another account

Tags: mysql

I(with root account) create some procedure `myproc` which has some part of code below:

```
declare cur_uname varchar(20);
select substring_index(current_user(),'@', 1) into cur_uname;
```

Then I create another account `abc@localhost` with `GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE mydb.myproc TO 'abc'@'localhost';`.
When I execute `myproc` under account `abc@localhost`,`cur_uname` is `root` but not `abc`. What should I address this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [CURRENT_USER()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_current-user):

  > Within a stored program or view, `CURRENT_USER()` returns the account for the user who defined the object (as given by its `DEFINER` value) unless defined with the `SQL SECURITY INVOKER` characteristic. In the latter case, `CURRENT_USER()` returns the object's invoker.
- [USER()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_user):

  > Returns the current MySQL user name and host name as a string in the `utf8` character set. [...] The value indicates the user name you specified when connecting to the server, and the client host from which you connected. The value can be different from that of `CURRENT_USER()`.

So I guess it all depends on the definition of "correct" that you need.